# Angular: whether to use *.constant.ts or .constant.json for storing constants and configs

Tags: json, angular, typescript, constants

I am using angular for my project and I used to create a `constants` folder here I have different constant files to keep static data and configs, as shown below.

File: constans/menu.constant.ts

```
export const menu = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', icon: 'icon-dashboard', routerLink: '/dashboard' },
  { name: 'Members', icon: 'icon-members', routerLink: '/member' },
  {
    name: 'Product',
    icon: 'icon-product',
    routerLink: '/product',
    nestedMenu: [
      { name: 'Product List', icon: 'fa-table', routerLink: '/product/list' },
      { name: 'Category', icon: 'fa-table', routerLink: '/category' },
      { name: 'Collection', icon: 'fa-table', routerLink: '/collection' },
      { name: 'Brand', icon: 'fa-table', routerLink: '/brand' }
    ]
  },
  { name: 'Content', icon: 'icon-content', routerLink: '/content' },
  {
    name: 'Store Mangement',
    icon: 'icon-store',
    routerLink: '/store-management'
  },
  {
    name: 'Settings',
    icon: 'icon-settings',
    nestedMenu: [
      { name: 'Tax Groups', icon: 'fa-table', routerLink: '/tax-groups' }
    ]
  }
];
```

But one of my friends suggested me to go for .json files instead of ts files for defining constant and configs because he says the ts file will be clubbed into the final build js file, which eventually increases my build size. But using JSON file my build js file size won't be affected as JSON will not merge into js.

This is how he said to use:

File: constans/menu.constant.json

```
{
   "sidebarMenu": [
      {
         "name": "Dashboard",
         "icon": "icon-dashboard",
         "routerLink": "/dashboard"
      },
      {
         "name": "Members",
         "icon": "icon-members",
         "routerLink": "/member"
      },
      {
         "name": "Product",
         "icon": "icon-product",
         "routerLink": "/product",
         "nestedMenu": [
            {
               "name": "Product List",
               "icon": "fa-table",
               "routerLink": "/product/list"
            },
            {
               "name": "Category",
               "icon": "fa-table",
               "routerLink": "/category"
            },
            {
               "name": "Collection",
               "icon": "fa-table",
               "routerLink": "/collection"
            },
            {
               "name": "Brand",
               "icon": "fa-table",
               "routerLink": "/brand"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "Content",
         "icon": "icon-content",
         "routerLink": "/content"
      },
      {
         "name": "Store Mangement",
         "icon": "icon-store",
         "routerLink": "/store-management"
      },
      {
         "name": "Settings",
         "icon": "icon-settings",
         "nestedMenu": [
            {
               "name": "Tax Groups",
               "icon": "fa-table",
               "routerLink": "/tax-groups"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Can anyone put some more light on these to find the best-optimized solution?

Comment: `.ts` files are easier to work with so I'd go with that.

Comment: I'd go with TS because you can put comments in TS, unlike JSON, and that can be useful in a config file.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is wrong.

Data is data. If you use, it needs to be loaded from the server. let it be TS, JSON, plain text or binary, it **will** be loaded no matter what.

And to answer more directly your question, you should use `environment` files, which are environment-related. Creating constant files is just duplicating a logic that already exists.

## Edit

After testing on my own what you friend has said with

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as data from './app.data.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = data.some;
}

---- JSON ----

{
  "some": "data"
}
```

And outputing a dist foled like

[image]

i can confirm that this isn't true at all, JSON is treated like any TS. I even opened the first `main.XXX.js` file and found it :

```
function(e){e.exports=JSON.parse('{"a":"data"}')}
```

Comment: Since ts will be minified it will probably even be less data to be loaded. I think an environment file is wrong for a menu config though.

Comment: @chrispbacon true that

Comment: I am not talking of environment-specific constants, I am talking of constants and configs that will be same throughout the project.

Comment: @VarunSukheja and it still should be done into `environment` files. They should all inherit a base evnironment, which would equate your "constants".

Comment: @chrispbacon tried with a project on my own, the JSON gets minified too (see edit on my answer)

Comment: Oh wow, didn't know that. @Maryannah Thanks for mentioning, that's interesting